# Stereoscopic SBS is anaglyphic

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Trying to render an image with 2.76 and cycles in SBS (Squeezed Frame) or line-interleaved still renders that anaglyphic red/blue thing in the viewport. (To be more clear, I'm talking about the F12-render and the result in the image editor.) The result should be in real colors. What am I doing wrong?

Only when I save, it saves a image_L.jpg and an image_R.jpg. Those are in real colors but not line-interleaved nor side by sidy squeezed.

[image: Viewport]

Comment: This only answers your first question (it's the only question, but I assume you're more interested in getting the output image right). In the bottom bar of the render view there is an icon that looks like a couple of glasses with green/red lenses. Click it and it will turn off the anaglyphic look. It won't look 3d at all then, however.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off anaglyphic view by pressing the icon at the bottom row (looks like a pair of glasses? with red/green lenses).

To save as one image, select "Save As Image". When deciding file name, you have a panel at the left, this is where you select the format of the output. The window in the rendering panel doesn't seem to do anything useful.