# How to use the stereoscopic 3D Side-By-Side view?

Tags: 3d-view, uv-image-editor, stereoscopy

When working with `Render Layers/Views` turned on for stereoscopic 3D mode, I can preview the 3D in the OpenGL viewport's camera view <kbd>numpad 0</kbd> in anaglyph (red/cyan glasses etc). That works fine.

But I'd like to also be able to use the Side-By-Side (cross-eyed) mode for previewing in the OpenGL viewport.

When I go to `Window/Set Stereo 3D` I can change to side-by-side cross-eyed, and I get a message saying `Stereo 3D mode requires that the window be fullscreen.`

But no matter how I switch to fullscreen I never see a Side-By-Side image. I've tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>up arrow</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, all inside and outside of the camera view, but I never see any side-by-side view.

Is it possible to see a cross-eyed side-by-side view in the OpenGL viewport?

If it's not possible in the OpenGL viewport, is it at least possible to see a rendered image in cross-eyed side-by-side in the UV/Image Editor? Not even that works.

I AM able to save a PNG in side-by-side cross-eyed format. The option from the save menu work fine and will produce a side-by-side cross eyed PNG file. But I don't know how to use the option in either OpenGL preview or in render preview in the UV/Image editor.

I am using Blender 2.78a on Xubuntu Linux. Thanks to anyone for any help.

### Related questions:

[3D render - requested side-by-side but got anaglyphic - how to fix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63025/3d-render-requested-side-by-side-but-got-anaglyphic-how-to-fix)
This question just talks about how to use the Save Image options to get a side-by-side PNG file. That is not my problem; saving a PNG works fine.

[How do I use Blender's built-in stereoscopic features?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52139/how-do-i-use-blenders-built-in-stereoscopic-features?rq=1) Again, just talking about saving a PNG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch fullscreen mode press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>.

In the Info Area, go to **Window > Toggle Fullscreen**.

A search in the [Blender Documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/info/introduction.html#window) also display the menu location and keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a 4th hotkey for fullscreen!(!!) (I love Blender, but we reached hotkey critical mass years ago)