# Composite multiple cameras in one image

Tags: scene, render-layers, compositing-nodes

I need to create a workflow where I can composite 13 cameras together in a file, all filming from different angles in a scene, with different resolutions for each.

I already created 13 seperated scene, all linked together, to have 13 different active cameras.
I then try to composite them together, by translating them where I need them to be, and then adding them to a master picture, which size is what I want for the final picture :
[image: Composition Setup]

(The result in the backdrop is part of what I want. The viewer is linked to the second add node.)

But when I try to render the whole thing, with a composition node at the end
[image: Composite Node]

My final render is only white, where it should have've been strips of white corresponding to the renders from my different camera.

When I click the render button from individual Render Layers node, I get the correct sized strips, but when I try to render the whole thing, I only get white. I can't make it work that way since it will be animated.

Sorry if I'm not clear, I only started Blender recently. I would be happy to provide additional information.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: if you only started Blender recently...and you do this...you have my full respect! When i started Blender i was following Donut tutorials and didn't finish them ever....

Comment: See my answer in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77. Basically this is an "abuse" of the Compositor capabilities. It kind of works but it is hacky and requires a force refresh

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thansk for the response. Unfortunately, I can't realistically use this force refresh method since I have 13 cameras, and will be using this setup for animations. Do you know any other way I could make it work  ? Would scripting resolve that issue ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rendering to disk as separate image files and compositing in a second step? If composited in a separate file this issue should theoretically avoided. Another possible trick is to use a a large image with the size of the desired file output as compositing base to try and force the correct size.

Comment: I will try that and will be getting back to you if that works.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar need to composite several scenes in the same image. These are images from separate scenes that I'm using as a storyboard workflow. Each image is 1920x1080. This is what I came up with:

[image]