# Compose the output of Stereoscopy (Multi-View with 4 cameras) into a single image with 2x2 slots

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is it possible to combine renders from 4 cameras into a single 2x2 split-screen static image? (with single "Render Image" action)

Using the Stereoscopy feature we can render from several cameras with single F12-hit. Using Scale/Translate/Mix nodes we can also arrange images over/next to each other.

But I don't know how to point to the render output of particular camera in the Compositor. Is that even possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way is probably to have

- one *Scene* with four *Cameras*
- second *Scene* in the same blend for merging cameras into single image

In second empty Scene

- switch to *VSE* layout
- add a *Scene* strip (with cameras) and in properties set specific *Camera* object

... repeat for all four cameras and arrange strips in viewer for render.

[image]