# Four views face rendering

Tags: rendering

How can I do the rendering technique shown in the photo with Blender?

I have a 3D model (Person's head) and I am trying to render it in a way that shows its four sides simultaneously, just like the image that I uploaded.

[image: uploaded image]

I need such a visualization in order to use it for projecting a hologram using a pyramid display.

Actually, the work shown in the figure was done with OpenGL using the glViewport to get four viewports that can contain the object from four views and I am trying to do the same work but this time using Blender, this is the whole story.

I have also duplicated my object into four different views but when I try to render the whole scene I get only a part of it because the camera is not getting the four views together.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Baccar Ala, I suspect this is a question that can get a nice complete answer in minutes if you clarify what you mean and form it in a specific manner.

Comment: I have a 3D model (Person's head) and I am trying to render it in a way that shows its four sides simultaneously, just like the image that I uploaded, I hope this explanation makes things more clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but to me the question is still not clear. Can't you just duplicate the model 3 times and rotate the copies by 90° each time to create such an image? Maybe show what have you tried and where you are stuck? What do you mean by "rendering technique"?

Comment: Actually, the work shown in the figure was done with OpenGL using the glViewport to get four viewports that can contain the object from four views and I am trying to do the same work but this time using blender, this is the whole story. Anyways thanks very much for your prompt response.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Do you want to render an image like this https://i.imgur.com/PkMSTkF.jpg?

Comment: Yes exactly, I have also duplicated my object into four different views as you did but when I try to render the whole scene I get only a part of it because the camera is not getting the four views together.

Comment: Do you use 4 different 3D viewports in Blender and try to render an image from these? Maybe create a little demo with Suzanne (*Add > Mesh > Monkey*) and add a screenshot of it to your question and the camera settings (focal length). The question is closed but you can edit it and it can be re-opened. Blender renders (F12) what the camera sees. If the camera can't capture all 4 at the same time you might need to adjust the camera's focal length and its distance to the objects.

Comment: @Blunder what's the point of using 4 different viewports (what does that even mean?) when you could just duplicate it 4 times around a curve? (referring to the OP)

Comment: @Blunder Oh I guess you mean "views"

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52231/rendering-a-stereoscopic-image-in-blender-2-77

Comment: The problem is kinda solved, thank you very much guys for your patience, very much appreciated.