How to set the output resolution for compositor?
The compositor output always match/follow to the render output setting.
How to set the compositor resolution to be different from the render resolution ?
For example my render resolution is 1920 x 1080 and I want the output of the compositor to be 1000x1000 ?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57870/19307

Regarding the case of your example with a 16:9 render and a 1:1 output, do you want to crop the render or distort the render to fit the different aspect ratio? And if you want to crop it, crop it absolute or first scale down to fit one length and then crop the overlap?

If you use File Output nodes, the compositor will output whatever the size of the thing you want to output is. So if you create a new mask and set its node to a fixed size it will output that size, if you then mix something over it with Alpha Over or Color Mix nodes it will become that resolution.
You create a new mask in the Image Editor by switching it's mode to "Mask":



